# Passwordless SSH no longer works on macOS

Tags: ssh

I've been using passwordless `ssh` for at least a couple years now, but it's been a long time since I needed to `ssh` into my laptop for any reason. So I was shocked to find out that it no longer works!

My public key (`id_rsa.pub`) is still in my `authorized_keys` file like it should be, but for whatever reason, my system isn't accepting it anymore. In addition, when I created a new key with `ssh-keygen` and added it to `authorized keys`, the new key didn't work either. All the files in my `.ssh` folder have `600` permissions and the `.ssh` folder itself has `700` permissions.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?
I'm running macOS Sierra (10.12.2).

Here's some debug output below, slightly edited for brevity:

```
09:38 [mchenja .ssh]$ diff -s id_rsa.pub authorized_keys 
Files id_rsa.pub and authorized_keys are identical

09:39 [mchenja .ssh]$ ssh -v localhost

.
.
.

debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mchenja/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mchenja/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mchenja/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mchenja/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mchenja/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

Comment: I'm on a relatively fresh install of Sierra and it works for me, even with keys generated on my old system.  Did you check the permissions for allowed users?  Assuming you are using the Apple provided sshd, that would be in system preferences.    Does your password work when you do type it?

Comment: @eggo huh, weird. Yes, I'm able to use my password with SSH and have it work normally, so I'm sure it's not a permissions or firewall issue. Thanks for the suggestion, though - any other ideas?

Comment: No concrete ideas, but you might try either (a) moving your entire .ssh directory out of the way and using ssh-key-gen to start afresh, or (b) essentially the same thing with a new, temporary user on the same system.  Could be something with the keyring (for key passphrases) or ????